# Java round to nearest .5

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

How is this possible in Java?

I have a float and I'd like to round it to the nearest .5.

For example:

1.1 should round to 1.0

1.3 should round to 1.5

2.5 should round to 2.5

3.223920 should round to 3.0

**EDIT**: Also, I don't just want the string representation, I want an actual float to work with after that.

Comment: Multiply by two, round and finally divide by two

Comment: I tried countless different inputs in Google and nothing gave me that post.

Comment: @user1513171 I just googled: [round to nearest 0.5 java](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=round+to+nearest+0.5+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-MX:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=91ZlU9jaN6iR8QfP4YD4Dw) that way and gave me so many posts from SOF

Comment: I googled this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=round+to+nearest+0.5+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:es-MX:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=91ZlU9jaN6iR8QfP4YD4Dw#channel=sb&q=round+to+nearest+.5+java&rls=org.mozilla:es-MX:official

But whatever. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Google ignores punctuation, so you were essentially searching for 'round to the nearest 5 in java' : https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

Answer (score 46, accepted):

@SamiKorhonen said this in a comment:

> Multiply by two, round and finally divide by two

So this is that code:

```
public static double roundToHalf(double d) {
    return Math.round(d * 2) / 2.0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d1 = roundToHalf(1.1);
    double d2 = roundToHalf(1.3);
    double d3 = roundToHalf(2.5);
    double d4 = roundToHalf(3.223920);
    double d5 = roundToHalf(3);

    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);
    System.out.println(d3);
    System.out.println(d4);
    System.out.println(d5);
}
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.5
2.5
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: i like this code... i will put in my inventory.. thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind that Math.round(-83.25*10)/10f and Math.round(83.25*10)/10f will give you -83.2 and 83.3 result.

Answer (score 10):

The general solution is

```
public static double roundToFraction(double x, long fraction) {
    return (double) Math.round(x * fraction) / fraction;
}
```

In your case, you can do

```
double d = roundToFraction(x, 2);
```

to round to two decimal places

```
double d = roundToFraction(x, 100);
```

Comment: What if I want to round to nearest .75? Would I pass 4/3 instead of 2? Thanks

Comment: @theprogrammer that would be the nearest multiple of 0.75, e.g. 1.5, 2.25, 3.00. If you wanted the nearest number ending in 0.75, subtract 0.75, round it and add 0.75 back.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is not that elegant, you could create your own Round function similarly to the following (it works for positive numbers, it needs some additions to support negatives):

```
public static double roundHalf(double number) {
    double diff = number - (int)number;
    if (diff < 0.25) return (int)number;
    else if (diff < 0.75) return (int)number + 0.5;
    else return (int)number + 1;
}
```