# Android get calculation result with decimal

Tags: android

I'm making some calculations on my project in order to see how many trucks could be parked on a road of X meters.

I have this:

```
    int road1 = 140;
    double trucks = 0;
    
    trucks = (road1-10)/20;
System.out.println("trucks"+trucks);
```

The problem is that if you calculate by yourself, the result will be 6.5.
So you could park 6.5 trucks.

But I always get 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the calculation with ints, if you change to `trucks = (road1-10)/20.0` you will get the answer 6.5

Comment: The expression will be evaluated _first_ & then cast to double only at assignment, but by that stage you've already lost (truncated) the decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, I still can't mark as solved so I will do it in 6'.

Comment: What if I get 6.8 and I want to round to 6.5?

Comment: Round to nearest half is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449662/java-round-to-nearest-5

Comment: Thanks @Per.J but I want to round down, the linked solution is rounding up

Comment: @Giovanni replace `Math.round` with `Math.floor`